# What does the @title batch script command do?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I see it a few times in my batch script, however I'm not certain what it actually does. The two occurrences of it are below an @echo (which prints out the text following it to the console) and are exact duplicates of the text that is printed with @echo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not surprisingly, it [sets the title](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/title.mspx?mfr=true) of the command prompt window the batch is running in.  The leading `@` keeps the line from being echo'd to the prompt.

Answer (score 28):

- `@` means "don't echo this, just run it."
- `title` lets you set the title of the cmd.exe window.

Try `title /?` from the command prompt.

Answer (score 7):

It sets the title of the current command window title bar.

If you run the following script as a batch file, you will see an example:

```
@title = "My Title"
pause
```

Comment: Surrounding the title in quotes will print the quotes, just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

It "specifies the title for the command prompt window" (found by running `title /?`).

Comment: Interesting...I've never seen it actually change the title of the window before...